# Web app that runs in Microsoft Teams (personal tab) doesn't always work on Desktop version

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

I have a Web app built in Vuejs and has **SSO authentification** using `microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken` when running in Teams, or `microsoftAuthLib` when running in the browser.

Inside the company's network or when connected to the VPN everything works absolutely fine.

We recently opened it outside of the VPN and we created a public certificate for it. So when I disconnect the VPN, it works:

- In any browser (outside of Teams).
- Teams browser version.
- Teams on Android/iPhone.

But it doesn't work on Teams Windows Desktop version, it fails with the following error:

> Refused to display
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/authorize?...' in a
> frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Anybody has an idea what could be the issue? And why would it work on the company's VPN but not outside?And only on specific cases? I am lost, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

*** EDIT / ADDED SSO REDIRECT CODE ***

```
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";
import * as microsoftAuthLib from "msal";
import settings from './settings.js';

var msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: settings.sso.id,
        authority: settings.sso.authority
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
};

var requestObj = {
    scopes: settings.sso.scopes
};

var myMSALObj = new microsoftAuthLib.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);

function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {

    if (error) {

        console.log(error);

    } else {

        console.log("token type is:" + response.tokenType);
    }
}

function loginRedirect(requestObj) {

    let account = myMSALObj.getAccount();

    if (!account) {

        myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);

        return false;

    } else {

        return true;
    }
}

function acquireMsalToken() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {

        resolve(myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(token => {

            return token.accessToken;

        }).catch(error => {

            acquireMsalTokenRedirect(error);
        }));
    })
}

function acquireTeamsToken() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({

            successCallback: (result) => {
                resolve(result);
            },

            failureCallback: (error) => {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function acquireMsalTokenRedirect(error) {

    if (error.errorCode === "consent_required" ||
        error.errorCode === "interaction_required" ||
        error.errorCode === "login_required") {

        myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(requestObj);
    }
}

var msal = {

    autoSignIn: function () {

        return loginRedirect(requestObj);
    },

    acquireToken: async function () {

        if (settings.sso.inTeams) {

            microsoftTeams.initialize();
            microsoftTeams.enterFullscreen();

            return acquireTeamsToken();

        } else {

            let signedIn = msal.autoSignIn();

            if (signedIn) {

                return acquireMsalToken();
            }
        }
    }

}

export default msal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the acquireTeamsToken() function with the following resolved the issue.

```
function acquireTeamsToken() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {

            microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({

                url: window.location.origin + "/ms-teams/auth-start",
                width: 600,
                height: 535,

                successCallback: (result) => {
                    resolve(result);
                },

                failureCallback: (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I found this documentation very helpful on how to create the Authentication pop up and how to create a Callback window with the Token in it.
You might also want to cache the token and only create a popup when it expires.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are trying to redirect your tab's iframe to the AAD login flow which in turn is unable to silently generate an auth token for you and is attempting to show an interactive flow (e.g. sign in or consent):

> Refused to display
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/authorize?...' in a
> frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

To avoid this issue you need to try and acquire a token silently and if that fails use the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` API to open a popup window and conduct the AAD login flow there.

Comment: You're right! Replacing my silent authentication workflow with a popup solved the issue, although I couldn't capture the error from the failure callback in the promise (because the app crashes in the Team's iFrame and doesn't return the error). I cached the token in localStorage and acquire a new one when it expires.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're using the auth popup option instead of the redirect option in whichever auth library you're using (hopefully MSAL 2.0). Teams is a little different because it's actually launching a popup *for you* when necessary, so although it sounds a bit strange, you actually want to use the *redirect* option, inside the popup that is launched. What might help is to look at the new [SSO Sample app](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso) in the Teams PnP samples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am actually doing an SSO redirect which is the default Teams workflow as documented when using @microsoft/teams-js. 

microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken as a success callback that returns the token. Teams does the redirect internally in an iframe. Which works fine all the time until I hate the specific scnearios I mentioned. Which is weird to me :(

Comment: can you post a code sample of your redirect?

Comment: I added the my sso code above. Thx! 
Question tho, if the issue is in the redirect then why would it work in Ms Teams when I connect the company's VPN but it stops working when I disconnect it? Also does the Teams browser version handle it differently? Because it works in the browser in any case. Thx!

Comment: I don't think the *Teams* browser is the issue - usually it's an environmental issue of the the browser in general, versus a desktop app. What I mean is that a browser usually already has a login context, which the desktop might not, for instance. As to why it works on VPN, try use Fiddler or similar maybe to track the journey, it might show the issue.

Comment: Issue is resolved! Here is the solution in case someone has the same issue:
- Go to: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams
- Open the file hooks.json (if it's not there, create it)
- Add the following to it: {"enableSso": false, "enableSsoMac": false}
     That's it, now Teams desktop has the same authentication workflow as the browser version.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams
- Open the file hooks.json (if it's not there, create it)
- Add the following to it: {"enableSso": false, "enableSsoMac": false}

That's it, now Teams desktop has the same authentication workflow as the browser version. Have a nice day.

Comment: Turning off SSO for the Teams Desktop Client is not a good idea and will probably lead to other issues down the road (e.g. requiring the user to sign into the Teams Client again even though they are already signed into Windows, not being able to use Teams due to Conditional Access policies, etc.). Implementing SSO for your app/tab correctly as per the documentation here is the best option:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso

If done right, it would not require users to hack their Teams Client in this fashion.

Comment: You're right! I ran into multiple issues especially when switching VPN ON/OFF. Replacing my silent authentication workflow with a popup solved the issue for me. I will post the solution.